# React Native - Too Many Re-Renders

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, if-statement

I am trying to create a state where it shows the visibility of some components depending on if the props are not empty. I have used an if statement as shown in the code however, it creates an error where there are too many re-renders happening. If i set a default let showComponents = false or true, everything works fine. Any idea on how to fix this issue as the visibility of the components is dependent on if the props are empty or not.

Code:

```
const [showcComponents, setView] = useState(false);
...
if (props.params == undefined) {
setVisibility(false);
} else {
setVisibility(true);
}
```

Comment: please provide the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every update in sent to your component you are calling setVisibility(false/true). This is probably messing with the rendering method in react creating a rendering loop. You should try not to call a function outside a hook. Assuming you have a visibility variable you can try:

```js
...
useEffect(()=>{
    if(props.params === undefined && visibility === true){
         setVisibility(false);
    }else if(props.params !== undefined && visibility === false){
         setVisibility(true);
    }
}, [props.params]
)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will result in infinite re-render cycles. Because each time the component will render it will call `setVisibility` which will re-render the component

```
const [showcComponents, setView] = useState(false);
useEffect(()=>{
  if (props.params == undefined) {
    setVisibility(false);
  } else {
    setVisibility(true);
  }
}, [props.params])
```

Also you can write is shorter like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setVisibility(props.params !== undefined);
}, [props.params])
```